# Flutter app stay running while in background

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an app I have building that is giving navigation from a location to a location. Contstantly tracking where the user is using GPS data in order to give good Directional information. Currently if a user switches from our app to another app or goes to the Android home screen, after one minute Android turns off our app for performance reasons.

I have tried using an Isolate but like flutter this gets shutdown. Next step were to use a kotlin service to handle background things but i wanted to check if anyone had done this in dart yet?

Also this is not an app that will be in the play store or on public devices. It is going on special devices that we control and are less worried about memory usage as this will be the main app ran on them.

Comment: Take a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @galloper... i will look into implementing this...

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned above in the comment by @galloper `background_fetch` is the thing you need, it has a method called `BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(backgroundFetchHeadlessTask);` where `backgroundFetchHeadlessTask` is a function that will keep running even when the app is close, i used this in my app to stream location info to server.